# Unable to get data from API in Android

Tags: android, api, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, dto

I'm having an issue on showing data in a Recycle View in Android. The data comes from an API that works fine as I tested it separately. I've implemented the DTO pattern because the data is located inside a data JSON within the main JSON.
I'm using Retrofit to get the data from the API.
I will leave the code below

ArticleActivity.Java

```
public class ArticleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private final String baseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/";
List<Article> listaArticles = new ArrayList<>();
ArticleAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView rvClientes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_article);

    rvClientes = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvClientes);  // change this ID

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    rvClientes.setLayoutManager(llm);

    adapter =  new ArticleAdapter(listaArticles);
    rvClientes.setAdapter(adapter);

    DividerItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(rvClientes.getContext(),llm.getOrientation());
    rvClientes.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

    ArticleService articleService = retrofit.create(ArticleService.class);

    Call<ArticlesDTO> callArticleDTO = articleService.getArticles();
    callArticleDTO.enqueue(new Callback<ArticlesDTO>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArticlesDTO> call, Response<ArticlesDTO> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                listaArticles = response.body().data;
                adapter = new ArticleAdapter(listaArticles);
                rvClientes.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArticlesDTO> call, Throwable t) {

        }

    });
   }
}
```

ArticleAdapter.Java

```
public class ArticleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.ArticleViewHolder> {

    List<Article> lista;


    public ArticleAdapter(List<Article> lista) {
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    @Override
    public ArticleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.article_row,parent,false);
        return new ArticleViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ArticleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindArticle(lista.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    public class ArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvNombre;
        TextView tvId;



        public ArticleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvNombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvArticle);
            tvId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvID);

        }

        public void bindArticle(Article article) {
            String nombre = article.getTitle() + ":";
            tvNombre.setText(nombre);
            tvId.setText(String.valueOf(article.getId()));
        }

    }
}
```

ArticlesDTO

```
public class ArticlesDTO {
     public String status;
     public String message;
     public List<Article> data;

}
```

ArticleService

```
public interface ArticleService {
    @GET("api/v1/articles")
    Call<ArticlesDTO> getArticles();
}
```

The problem is, when I open The app It shows nothing but a blank screen with no errors. I put breakpoints to check the array  list size and it's zero

Comment: What's the specific problem? What happens when the program is "unable to get data"?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question because I forgot to mention the output

Comment: You're ignoring response inside `onFailure()` method.  `the array list size and it's zero` doesn't mean your API _always_ returns success response. You need to log the error inside `onFailure()` using `Log.e("tag", "API Error ", t);` then [edit] the question and post error log here (if there any errors). And also do not assign `adapter` object every single time you get response from API. Check @Vishal s answer below.

Comment: Hi I have checked your API using API test client tool. Your endpoint is not working.
I have tried this URL (http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/articles/)

Comment: @AnupaDayaratne you are aware that you tried to reach your own machine with IP 127.0.0.1 which is the loopback device?

Answer (score 2):

You are setting a new adapter whenever you are getting response from the API

```
//here is the problem

if (response.isSuccessful()) {
   listaArticles = response.body().data;
   adapter = new ArticleAdapter(listaArticles);
   rvClientes.setAdapter(adapter);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

instead use the existing adapter and then add data to the adapter

```
public void addAll(List<Article> data){
   this.lista = data;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and then when you get your repsonse

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
   listaArticles = response.body().data;
   adapter.addAll(listaArticles);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are hitting the wrong url (http://127.0.0.1:3000/)
This is a localhost url and can not be used form android device.
Try deploying your back end service on cloud and provide the appropriate base url to android app.